# Cordova Social Sharing Plugin not working in NetBeans 8 Cordova Build

Tags: netbeans, cordova-3, cordova-plugins

I installed Social Sharing Plugin using Command Prompt in my cordova 3.3 project of NetBeans 8
https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin
After successful plugin installation. The social sharing plugin is listed in the plugins folder. But when is try to build and run the app. Netbeans builder automatically removes the installed social sharing plugin. Check the log below

```
check-android-template:
check-cordova-version:
check-cordova-project:
upgrade-to-cordova-project:
create-android:
update-plugins:
cordova.cmd plugins 
cordova.cmd -d plugin remove nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing
Calling plugman.uninstall on plugin "nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing" for platform "android"
Uninstalling nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing from android
Beginning processing of action stack for android project...
```

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans' build process parses list of plugins declared via Project properties (for so-called "core" plugins known by NetBeans) or from plugin.properties file (actually in project properties NetBeans reads this file and display/adds core plugins from/to it). Have a look at [this screenshot](https://netbeans.org/images_www/articles/80/webclient/cordova-getstart/cordova-properties-plugins.png), it says that you can add custom plugins by modifying nbproject/plugins.properties file. If you add the Social sharing plugin to this file, you should be OK.